# Least positive integer $n$ such that the digit string of $2^n$ ends on the digit string of $n$

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

> What is the least positive integer $n$ such that the digit string of $2^n$ ends on the digit string of $n$:
>   $$ (2^n)_{10} = d_m \, d_{m-1} \cdots
>  d_{q+1} \, (n)_{10} \\ (n)_{10} = d'_{q} \cdots d_1' \\ d_i, d'_j \in
>  \{0, \ldots, 9 \} $$

As in $2^3$ would somehow end in 3, or $2^5$ would end in 5.

Frankly I don't even know where to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to solve $2^n \equiv n \pmod{10}$?

Comment: What does the question even mean?

Comment: Let's say that $2^3$ is 2423, then that would be counted a solution, because 2423 ends in a 3. But $2^3$ is 8, so that isn't a solution.

Comment: What if $n=12$, you want a solution $2^{12} = XXXXX12$?

Comment: Exactly. That's what it is

Comment: See OEIS sequence [A064541](https://oeis.org/A064541)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a less brute-force method:

In order for the digit string of $2^n$ to end with the digit string of $n$, it is necessary (but not sufficient) that $2^n$ and $n$ have the same last digit, i.e. $2^n \equiv n \pmod{10}$.

It is easy to check that $\begin{cases}2^n \equiv 2\pmod{10} & \text{if} \ n\equiv 1 \pmod{4} \\ 2^n \equiv 4\pmod{10} & \text{if} \ n\equiv 2 \pmod{4} \\ 2^n \equiv 8\pmod{10} & \text{if} \ n\equiv 3 \pmod{4} \\ 2^n \equiv 6\pmod{10} & \text{if} \ n\equiv 0 \pmod{4}\end{cases}$.

Since $2^n$ is even, $n$ must also be even. So we have the following 2 possibilities:

$n \equiv 2\pmod{4}$ AND $n \equiv 2^n \equiv 4\pmod{10}$, i.e. $n \equiv 14 \pmod{20}$

$n \equiv 0\pmod{4}$ AND $n \equiv 2^n \equiv 6\pmod{10}$, i.e. $n \equiv 16 \pmod{20}$.

So we only need to check $n \equiv 14 \ \text{or} \ 16 \pmod{20}$.

Since $2^{14} = 16384$, $2^{16} = 65536$, $2^{34} = 17179869184$, and $2^{36} = 68719476736$, the smallest positive integer $n$ such that the digit string of $2^n$ ends with the digit string of $n$ is $n = 36$.

Answer (score 10):

I just started checking numbers in a calculator.

The first $n$ I got such that $2^{n} = \dots n$ is $n = 36$.  We have $2^{36} = 68,719,476,736$.

Comment: Pretty unconventional way to do it- How would you do it for the other powers, other than 5?

Comment: @copper.hat: But they don’t satisfy the requirement that $2^n$ end in the usual decimal representation of $n$.

Comment: @bleh As I read your question, I understood it to be that you want the least positive integer $n$ so that $2^{n}$, when multiplied out, has $n$ as the last digits.  So I just checked $2^{3}, 2^{4}, 2^{5}, \dots$ in a calculator.  The first $n$ that gave me $n$ as the last digits of $2^{n}$ was $n = 36$.  Am I interpreting your question incorrectly?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I was answering a question which had been elaborated in the comments. Those comments seem to have disappeared. The 'Exactly. That it' comment was a response to user46944's comment.

Comment: @copper.hat not mod 10

Comment: @user46944 Yes you are

Comment: @copper.hat: You’re right. I misread it as a response to yours, but the time stamps clearly show otherwise.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott OP responded to copper.hat's comment, not mine.  That's why I deleted my original ocmment under the question.  copper.hat's interpretation of the question was the one that received a response by OP.  The comment with XXXX12 in it.

Answer (score 2):

This OEIS sequence is just what you are looking for: https://oeis.org/A064541. Least number is 36.

Answer (score 1):

I checked up to $n = 3 \cdot 10^5$ and the only solutions are $36, 736, 8736, 48736$.  It also turns out that $948736$, $2948736$, $32948736$ are solutions, each of which I found by prepending $1 \dots 9$ to the previous solution.  It seems a plausible conjecture that the solutions are the suffixes of some leftward-infinite decimal sequence, i.e. $n$ is a solution if and only if $n = \text{reverse}(\lfloor 10^k \cdot r \rfloor)$ where $k \ge 2$ and $r \approx 0.63784923$.

EDIT: Jesse P Francis and Robert Israel found the OEIS sequence and the terms listed there are consistent with that conjecture.  There is a link to [another sequence](https://oeis.org/A109405) with a simple recursive formula which is the same except it contains duplicates, apparently at the same positions where $0$ occurs in the digits of $r$ defined above.  The digits of $r$ are given by [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A133612).